# How to Embed and execute python using Python cli in HTML?

Tags: python, html

I need to intergrate python cli in HTML5. In order to execute basic commands and scripts. Similar to jupyter.. Is it possible to embed and execute python using python cli in html?

Comment: Do you want to execute the Python in the browser (there are Python to Javascript transpilers) or run the commands on the server as with Jupyter (danger, danger) ?

Comment: https://trinket.io/features/python3 could be what you want.

Comment: yep absolutely @BillBell

Comment: Or http://www.skulpt.org/, for its licensing.